# test error thrown using assert of node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm confused looking at the documention how we should test the error.

I have this divide function in index.js

```
function divide(dividend, divisor) {
    if(divisor === 0) {
      throw new Error('the quotient of a number and 0 is undefined');
    } else {
      return  dividend / divisor;
    }
  }
```

How should the test look like? I know it gonna be 2 case, the first one is to test the divide, I have no problem with it, but I have no clue how to test the error if user pass zero.

I'm using mocha and assert (node's assert)

```
describe('.divide', () => {
    it('returns the first number divided by the second number', () => {
      assert.equal(5, Calculate.divide(10,2))
    })

    it('throws an error when the divisor is 0', () => {

    })
})
```

Comment: `assert.throws` or `try/catch` with `assert` true/false (true in catch block).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The implementation code would look like this:

```
  divide(dividend, divisor) {
    if (divisor === 0) {
      throw new Error('the quotient of a number and 0 is undefined');
    } else {
      return dividend / divisor;
    }
  },
```

The test code would look like this:

```
it("returns an exception when the divisor is 0", () => {
  const dividend = 8;
  const divisor = 0;
  expected = Error;

  const exercise = () => Calculate.divide(dividend, divisor);

  assert.throws(exercise, expected);
})
```

This is according to the nodejs [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_throws_block_error_message)